# Add a .cshtml file to a Script Bundle in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, bundle

I have a cshtml file that has the following lines on top:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
    Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
}
```

When referenced directly from `_Layout.cshtml` in a script tag, it works fine. But I am trying to add it to a bundle, I understand that Optimization recently made it possible, if that is true, can someone show me how?

So this works fine

```
@Html.JsInclude(jslocation + "ui.data.cshtml?"); // normal script tag
```

While these give an error: Illegal character when they encounter the @, apparently the file never gets executed.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/uidata").Include(JsFolder + "ui.data.cshtml"));

@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/uidata");
```

Comment: what is @Html.JsInclude never seen/used it

Comment: oh its just a private function to output a normal script tag

Answer (score 0):

i dont know what `@Html.JsInclude` is doing but normally asp.net MVC engine will not render views directly. instead it demands that you call an ActionMethod which then returns a view.

so even if you try loading a view using script tag with url of the view it typically shouldnt work or if you have allowed direct access to the views folder and added `.cshtml` mime type to files that are sent upon a request. all the contents of the file will be send which will include all the content even if it is inside `@{}`

also with all this there is no use of making a bundle consisting contents of your view as a bundle is a minified copy and is **cached** so if you want it to be cached why just not send a script file across.

you probably are trying to inject a script dynamically. in which case send across the script directly by the controller with the appropriate `content-type header`

Comment: Actually, the only reason to make it a cshtml is because I want to manage text throughout javascript, these textual content that might appear in different places are bound to translation and are fed by resources, so there must be common ground between javascript and code behind (ui layer), unfortunately, obviously, I cannot bundle, minify, and cache this file.